# Problems Adding jinput Dependencies from Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8, jinput

I'm trying to add jinput to my project.  I'm using Netbeans as an IDE.  I'm really unable to find any resources on jinput that aren't broken or ancient.  I was really hoping the Maven approach would work but it seems it can't find the appropriate drivers which are stored as Runtime Dependencies.

Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>controller</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.jinput</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinput-platform</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.jutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>jutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.jinput</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinput-platform</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <classifier>natives-windows</classifier>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.jinput</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinput-platform</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <classifier>natives-linux</classifier>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.jinput</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinput-platform</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <classifier>natives-osx</classifier>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.jinput</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinput</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Here's the error I'm getting when I try to run one of the jinput test classes from their GIT repo:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jinput-raw_64 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
```

All the drivers are part of the jinput-platform dependency.  Note that the code itself has no compiler issues.  I'm fairly certain the issue is with finding the appropriate library during runtime.  Any recommendations?

Comment: I ended up extracting the window libraries from the Maven jar and sticking them in my project's root directory.  I'll probably add them to a directory and point the library path there, but I'd still really like to get it working correctly with just Maven (if possible).